# Asp.Net Core: There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created a new Asp.Net Core WebApi project and simply added IdentityDbContext, then i wrote in **Nuget Package Console** these commands:

```
PM> Add-Migration Initial
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
PM> Update-Database
Applying migration '20180516150423_Initial'.
Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [AspNetRoles] (
    [Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [NormalizedName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [AspNetRoles] (
          [Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
          [ConcurrencyStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [Name] nvarchar(256) NULL,
          [NormalizedName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
      );
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
ClientConnectionId:049426b7-c12c-421f-9236-c0212a40c216
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:049426b7-c12c-421f-9236-c0212a40c216
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
PM>
```

Google Drive project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16bYS7br2Ba7NcJYatPBDG2Q921o3MFcK

If you try to build this project you will help me very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database

The `AspNetRoles` table already exists.

Two things you could try:

1. Log into the database Server and run `drop database <your_db_name>`.
2. Change the database name in the connection string.

Now the `Add-Migration <MigrationClassName>` command will work.

Comment: But the point of ef migration is to keep the data? If I drop the db I will loose all of my data?

Comment: @Genfood the point of ef migrations is to give you control over the db schema (and changes to it) at the application level... you wont see the OPs error unless you: 1. delete your Migrations folder  2. or unless you use a connection string that is already used in an older project (in which case you'd want to update the database name in the connection string). During the initial phases of development, it's common to delete/recreate the db and the Migrations folder, and seed it with test data.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same bug as below. Then I fixed it as below:

1. Check current databases in your project:
   `dotnet ef migrations list`
2. If the newest is what you've added, then remove it:
   `dotnet ef migrations remove`
3. Guarantee outputs of this database must be deteled in source code: .cs/.Designer.cs files
4. Now it is fine. Try to re-add: 
   `dotnet ef migrations add [new_dbo_name]`

5.Finally, try to update again, in arrangement base on migration list:

`dotnet ef database update [First]`

`dotnet ef database update [Second]`

...

`dotnet ef database update [new_dbo_name]`

Hope it is helpful for you. ^^